# Turning a string of integers into a list and sorting it by odd and even elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a string of integers, such as `string = {11, 2, 14, 1, 17, 1, 123, 1}` What I need to do is turn it into a list, and then sort them into two separate lists of odd and even elements.

I had a dictionary that looked like `{11: 2, 14: 1, 17: 1, 123: 1}`, converted it to a string, and removed the colons into commas, so now I have the first string. I did this so I can split up the elements into having the numbers 11, 14, 17, and 123 in one list, and 2, 1, 1, and 1 in the other list.

I think I can convert this string into a list, and then use a loop to append each element into the list I need it to be. The problem is, I can't figure out how to turn this string into a list again. How would I do that? Alternatively, can I split the values the way I want straight from the dictionary and save steps? Thanks for any help

Comment: But `{11, 2, 14, 1, 17, 1, 123, 1}` isn't a string of integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can split the values straight from the dictionary! You'd use the `.keys()` and `.values()` on the dictionary object.

```
>>> obj = {11: 2, 14: 1, 17: 1, 123: 1}
>>> list(obj.keys())
[123, 17, 11, 14]
>>> list(obj.values())
[1, 1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

String conversion isn't necessary. In fact, there's no need to create a list of all keys for your problem. You can use `collections.defaultdict` and iterate your dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = {11: 2, 14: 1, 17: 1, 123: 1}

dd = defaultdict(list)

for key in x:
    dd['odd' if key % 2 else 'even'].append(key)
```

The result is a dictionary mapping of odd and even keys:

```
defaultdict(list, {'odd': [11, 17, 123],
                   'even': [14]})
```

You can then access odd keys via `dd['odd']`, even keys via `dd['even']`.

Answer (score 0):

To split a string into ints, use the built-in split method to return a list of each of the items:

```
new_list = string.split(", ")
```